# distributed postgres deployment out of sync

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, postgresql-9.4

I setup a distributed postgres database system and configured replication using hot_standby wal_level.

There is one central master database in place with multiple replicas (15 currently across the world) that are used as read only instances - so no need a failover - we just want to have the data synced to remote locations where we can read them.

master:

```
wal_level = hot_standby
max_wal_senders = 20
checkpoint_segments = 8    
wal_keep_segments = 8
```

clients:

```
wal_level = hot_standby
max_wal_senders = 3
checkpoint_segments = 8    
wal_keep_segments = 8 
hot_standby = on
```

/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/recovery.conf on Client side:

```
standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'host=<IP of master> port=5432 user=replicator password=xxxx sslmode=require'
trigger_file = '/tmp/postgresql.trigger'
```

the replication starts - all seems fine for some days.
after some days it seems there are no more connections accepted at the master for replication...

client:

```
2017-05-04 01:16:51 UTC [9608-1] FATAL:  could not connect to the primary server: FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already
2017-05-04 01:16:57 UTC [10807-1] FATAL:  could not connect to the primary server: FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already
2017-05-04 01:17:02 UTC [12022-1] FATAL:  could not connect to the primary server: FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already
2017-05-04 01:17:06 UTC [13217-1] FATAL:  could not connect to the primary server: FATAL:  remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
...
```

master:

and then the loag is full of the messages like below - and it never recovers...

```
2017-05-04 08:44:14 UTC [24850-1] replicator@[unknown] ERROR:  requested WAL segment 000000010000003500000014 has already been removed
2017-05-04 08:44:19 UTC [25958-1] replicator@[unknown] ERROR:  requested WAL segment 000000010000003500000014 has already been removed
2017-05-04 08:44:24 UTC [27063-1] replicator@[unknown] ERROR:  requested WAL segment 000000010000003500000014 has already been removed
2017-05-04 08:44:29 UTC [28144-1] replicator@[unknown] ERROR:  requested WAL segment 000000010000003500000014 has already been removed
2017-05-04 08:44:34 UTC [29227-1] replicator@[unknown] ERROR:  requested WAL segment 000000010000003500000014 has already been removed
2017-05-04 08:44:39 UTC [30316-1] replicator@[unknown] ERROR:  requested WAL segment 000000010000003500000014 has already been removed
...
```

client:

```
2017-04-30 11:26:22 UTC [28474-1] LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 35/14000000 on timeline 1
2017-04-30 11:26:22 UTC [28474-2] FATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 000000010000003500000014 has already been removed
2017-04-30 11:26:26 UTC [29328-1] LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 35/14000000 on timeline 1
2017-04-30 11:26:26 UTC [29328-2] FATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 000000010000003500000014 has already been removed
2017-04-30 11:26:31 UTC [30394-1] LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 35/14000000 on timeline 1
2017-04-30 11:26:31 UTC [30394-2] FATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 000000010000003500000014 has already been removed
...
```

so my question:

- is there an better way just to sync changes to remote read-only instances or do i just have errors in the configs that make my replication break after some time?

Comment: if you dont use archive_command (from your recovery.conf) to save WALs, and you dont have `000000010000003500000014` indeed, you have to rebuild replication

Comment: please decrease the number of questions to one essential, correlating to your log samples or config...

Comment: what do you mean with the below?
if you dont use archive_command (from your recovery.conf) to save WALs, and you dont have 000000010000003500000014

Comment: I mean slave could not connect to master for long enough time that it erased WAL you need to go on with replication

Comment: @VaoTsun: changed now to a single question.

Comment: it could not connect due to "could not connect to the primary server: FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already" - so is this a wrong setup i am running here? or just a too low connection limit for 15 replicas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-replication.html:

> max_wal_senders (integer)
>
> Specifies the maximum number of concurrent connections from standby
>   servers or streaming base backup clients (i.e., the maximum number of
>   simultaneously running WAL sender processes). The default is zero,
>   meaning replication is disabled. WAL sender processes count towards
>   the total number of connections, so the parameter cannot be set higher
>   than max_connections. **Abrupt streaming client disconnection might
>   cause an orphaned connection slot until a timeout is reached, so this
>   parameter should be set slightly higher than the maximum number of
>   expected clients** so disconnected clients can immediately reconnect.

(emphasis mine).
Either applications connecitons or orphan connections leaded to your

> `FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already`

You might want to use some connection pooler for applications, like pgbouncer, restricting too many connections before they actually happened.

Answering your question if you [have](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-ARCHIVE-COMMAND) `archive_command` set to actually copying WAL somewhere, modify restore_command in recovery.conf on slave to pick them up. It will allow slave to catch up from the moment it lost stream. Otherwise you have to rebuild it.

Comment: thx a lot! i will try to increase max_wal_senders to a higher number. further, i would like to get the archive_command and the restore_command working - do you have an example on what needs to be done?